# How to completely remove the self-signed certificate created with openssl

Tags: ssl, openssl, opensuse, ca

I created a self-signed certificate in a local pc and now I can't access to the localhost showing the following error in both chrome & firefox. There is no option to accept the risk and continue.

I tried removing the generated cert and key files but the issue is still there.

Is there way to rollback that change? Or any other way to continue.

[image]

[image]

```
OS: OpenSUSE Thumbleweed
```

Comment: It is unclear what you were doing. Simply creating a certificate does not magically install it somewhere nor does it setup a local web server. So you did more than you describe, but it is unclear what you actually did.

Answer (score 0):

HSTS is blocking you, so clear HSTS config in used browser for used domain (`locahost`). Random blog post how to do that: https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/clear-hsts-settings-chrome-firefox/